# Android fragment shader having problems

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, pixel

Sorry for the broad question, but I didn't know quite how to word it. I am creating an app that manipulates the camera's pixels. I am new to OpenGl and my problem could be in how I link textures to the shaders, or somewhere in my actual shader code.

I have an RGB look up table that I turn into a texture and pass into the shader to use as the manipulation table. I believe my texture is of the proper size and setting, but I am not 100% sure. In my shader I have this:

```
uniform sampler2D data_Texture // The RGB look up table texture
uniform samplerExternalOES u_Texture; // The camera's texture
```

And this is in my main loop in the shader:

```
// Color changing Algorithm
vec3 texel = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate).rgb;
gl_FragColor = vec4(texel.x, texel.y, texel.z, 1.0);

float rr = gl_FragColor.r * 255.0;
float gg = gl_FragColor.g * 255.0;
float bb = gl_FragColor.b * 255.0;

int r = int(rr);
int g = int(gg);
int b = int(bb);

int index = ((r/4) * 4096) + ((g/4) * 64) + (b/4);

int x = int(mod(float(index), 512.0));
int y = index / 512;

vec4 data = texture2D(data_Texture, vec2(float(x)/512.0, float(y)/512.0));
```

We take the camera's RGB pixels to get an index for the look up table. Then we try to get the rgb data out of the look up table to replace the camera's pixel with. This is where the problem occurs. As you can probably tell from the code above, we don't actually change the FragColor with our data. This is because we were testing and found an interesting occurrence. When we comment out the last line in the main loop,

```
//vec4 data = texture2D(data_Texture, vec2(float(x)/512.0, float(y)/512.0));
```

the camera just displays like normal, because we don't do any manipulations on the actual FragColor. But when we leave the last line in, the pixels turn green for dark colors and pink/orange for light colors.

Why does filling this data variable, and not explicitly changing the FragColor, change the camera's pixels??

Comment: Sounds like a driver bug.